# Installing CyanogenMod on Samsung Galaxy S

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-s

I have a *Samsung Galaxy S* and I tried to install CyanogenMod on it, but I messed up. Now when I try to boot up the phone it says "Samsung Galaxy S" and then "Samsung Galaxy S CynogenMod" – and repeats it for couple times and then it shuts down. Please help?

Comment: Ok, first thing to try would be to wipe the phone from recovery again, and reflash the ROM and try and reboot. Failing that try another ROM. In future, to save this stress, take a [tag:nandroid] backup in recovery, and keep the Zip it creates safe so you can restore your device at any time. Backup the backup onto your PC too. You can never have too many backups!!

Comment: Don't forget, wipe cache and dalvik-cache :)